# User reports "locked up" device

Tags: android, crash

I got this report (second hand) from a user of my Android app:

> Unfortunately after downloading the app and opening it my phone
>   stopped working immediately, was locked up and unusable. I took it to
>   a repair shop and they said the only fix was to wipe the phone clean
>   and start from scratch.

So far I don't have any other information such as type of device.  Besides getting more info from the user, does anyone have ideas on how to research something like this if it's even possible?  No developer or tester has ever had this happen, and it's the only report from a user that we've gotten.  It's always possible it's a coincidence but I doubt we could get the user to try it again to find out and it's disturbing to think our app could be doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company got me the same kind of device and I figured out (I think) that it was a huge icon file causing the problem.  For me, the symptom was the application list in settings crashing; I never got the "system UI has stopped" error.

Answer (score 0):

Without having hands on the device, there's nothing you can do.

I doubt that an App actually can put an (unrooted) device into a state where only factory reset helps, but factory reset is the all-time "have-you-tried-turning-it-off-and-on-again" solution for Android, so that's probably why the repair shop sugested that.

If it's possible for an app to so though, this is not your problem, but Androids one. It might be very well something the branding company messed up in their version of Android.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking.  Without root, I can't think how I could have done this even if I tried, and the app doesn't do anything exotic.  It's nice to say that it's Android's problem, but that doesn't really help smooth things over with clients.  Fortunately client communication is not my department!  Thanks very much for your input.